# ошибка при работе с LibGDX

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Осваиваю LibGDX, добавил Desktop конфигурацию и при ее запуске выдает такую ошибку

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'

Comment: Не уж то ошибку нельзя скопировать текстом? Зачем нам этот скриншот?

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ! Если у кого-то та же проблема, попробуйте зайти в File>settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Compiler и убрать галочку с пункта Configure on demand

Answer (score -1):

`File > settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler`

поставить галочку на `Sync project with Gradle before building`